# Physics pulley problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> A 64-kg housepainter stands on a 14-kg aluminum platform. The platform is attached to a rope that passes through an overhead pulley, which allows the painter to raise herself and the platform. (Ignore the mass of the rope, the pulley and any friction in the pulley.)
>
> (a) With what force $F$ must she pull down on the rope to accelerate herself and the platform upward at a rate of 0.74 m/s2?

This is a problem from my AP Physics class.
My work so far:

- $T - mg = ma$
- $T = ma + mg$
- $T = 78(.74+9.8)N$
- $T = 822 N$

But that not the correct answer. The answer is half of this and I don't understand why.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculated the force to accelerate the platform and painter upwards, and you got it right. But, the question doesn't ask about the total force; it asked about the force that the painter applies to the rope (which is the tension at every point in the rope).

Since the rope is connected to the platform in two places (once directly, once through the painter), the rope tension required is half the total force required. Hence your missing factor of two.

Comment: What I don't quite understand about this problem is how the internal forces are able to accelerate the system! Considering the painter and the platform to be the system, how is the painter able to apply a force on the system to cause it to accelerate? I'm confused...

Comment: The two ends of the rope pull on the pulley, which pulls on its axle, which is mounted somewhere fixed. So, the force is between that "somewhere fixed" and the rope/painter/platform.